# Finding Installed Browsers. Microsoft Edge

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to check for installed browsers on a client's PC as a means of enabling those browsers for use in the application. I've found that all browsers have information in the registry under

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet

and

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet
>   (64-bit)

with the exception of Microsoft Edge.

Its app settings are stored under

> Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Main

according to someone [here](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8141-microsoft-edge-downloads-folder-change-windows-10-a.html).

but I was hoping to find a neater solution that would encapsulate all browsers so am looking for ideas from people in the know.

Comment: Microsoft Edge is the default browser of Windows 10, and it is for Windows 10 only([Microsoft has no plans to bring Edge browser on any other platform beside Windows 10](http://news.softpedia.com/news/try-out-microsoft-edge-browser-without-installing-windows-10-489480.shtml)) I would assume it is installed if the OS is Windows 10. Or alternatively, you can check its default install location "C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe"

Comment: Generally it makes for better UX to just use the default browser (`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://whaterver.your.opening.com");`

Comment: I think I will go along the line of checking the os version for Windows 10 as it seems that although I can uninstall IE, I cannot uninstall Edge.

@Martijn I should have clarified why I need to know the installed browsers. We are doing automated testing of a web application so are launching all available installed browsers that we have test drivers for.

Comment: That's why I went for a comment, and was careful with the "genrally" :) Sometimes it difficult to spot if somebody wants to do something that's a bad idea, or if it's actually the right way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Microsoft Edge is the default browser, you can count that for granted and then you will find the remaining installed browsers from the registry.
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet`
 You can also use the following code snippet to detect the default browser.

```
@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice";
```

Comment: Rami, this is what I went for in the end. If the running executing OS is Windows 10, then we assume that Edge is installed, then go through the registry to get the remaining browsers.

Comment: We have to resort to the "Whatever Works" method sometimes :)

Comment: I am in Windows 11.  The first registry location worked great to get the list of browsers and their respective paths.  The second location (which is under HKEY_LOCAL_USER by the way) had a value, but I did not see how the "progid" found their matched up to an entry in the list.  Nonetheless, I found this answer helpful to get a list of installed browsers.